# Javascript how to filter an array using forEach() inside filter()

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

I have an array of objects and I'd like to filter it based on the objects property values. I'd like to filter it by different properties, so it needed to be dynamic. For this I have an input field where I type and then filter the array. So, let's say I have these 2 different arrays:

```
const array_one = [
  {id: 1, code: 'ABC123', name: 'John'},
  {id: 2, code: 'DEF456', name: 'Stew'},
    // ...
];

const array_two = [
  {id: 1, value: '012345', company: 'Company 01' },
  {id: 2, value: '678910', company: 'Company 02' },
    // ...
];
```

I want a function where I can filter the first array based on the `name`, also If I want to filter the second array, I want to filter it by the `value`.

For this, I built this function:

```
filterArray(array: Array<any>, fields: Array<any>, value: string) {
    value = this.convertString(value);

    array = array.filter((item) => {
        fields.forEach(obj => {
            if ( item[obj] ) {
                const _newObj = this.convertString(item[obj]);
                if ( _newObj.indexOf(value) !== -1 ) {
                    console.log(item);
                    return item;
                }
            }
        });
    });

    return array;
}
// convertString() is just another function to replace accents, spaces, etc...
```

Then I call it like this:

```
filterArray(originalArray, ['name'], valueFromInput);

// or...
filterArray(originalArray, ['value'], valueFromInput);

// or even...
filterArray(originalArray, ['value', 'company'], valueFromInput);
```

But the array filtered is always returnin empty, even if the console inside the `indexOf` verification prints the correct object on the console.

What am I doing wrong here? Because it's filtering properly, I have manually checked it, but it doesn't add to the new filtered array.

Comment: Please be more clear as to what result you're expecting. When using `forEach()`, returning something in the callback won't have any effect. If you wan't to map each item to something else, use `map()`. If you're defining a function body, like you do for your `filter()` callback, you have to use the `return` keyword otherwise that callback will implicitly return `undefined`

Comment: In JavaScript, forEach doesn't have a return value, so when you return item it's just being ignored. But filter requires a return value that can be coerced to a truthy or falsely value. You're not returning anything inside of filter, which is why you're not getting a filtered array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can iterate the `fields` using `Array#some`, and if one of them is equal to `value` return the `item`:

```js
const array_one = [
  {id: 1, code: 'ABC123', name: 'John'},
  {id: 2, code: 'DEF456', name: 'Stew'}
];

const array_two = [
  {id: 1, value: '012345', company: 'Company 01' },
  {id: 2, value: '678910', company: 'Company 02' }
];

const filterArray = (array, fields, value) => {
  fields = Array.isArray(fields) ? fields : [fields];
  
  return array.filter((item) => fields.some((field) => item[field] === value));
};
  
console.log(filterArray(array_one, 'name', 'Stew'));

console.log(filterArray(array_two, ['id', 'company'], 2));

console.log(filterArray(array_two, ['id', 'company'], 'Company 02'));
```

Comment: The only difference is that I need to check if the field contains the value instead of compare the full value, so I just changed to: `item[field].indexOf(value) !== -1`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to make the filter about more than one filed then the value that you send it to the function, should be also array.**
In my code below I assume that you want to return the object that Achieves all conditions (contains all properties that you send to the function with the same value)

```
 const array_one = [
      {id: 1, code: 'ABC123', name: 'John'},
      {id: 2, code: 'DEF456', name: 'Stew'},
   ];

   const array_two = [
      {id: 1, value: '012345', company: 'Company 01' },
      {id: 2, value: '678910', company: 'Company 02' },
   ];

   function filterArray(array, fields, value) {
       array = array.filter((item) => {
           const found = fields.every((field, index) => { 
               return item[field] && item[field] === value[index]
           })
           return found
       });
       return array;
   }

   console.log(filterArray(array_one, ['name'], ['Stew']));

   console.log(filterArray(array_two, ['id', 'company'], [1,'Company 01']));
```